# Configure Elmah email settings in code rather than config

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I'm setting up Elmah emails and I don't want to put my email account credentials in web.config.

I'm deploying on Azure and therefore would like to look up the credentials from Azure app settings in code on app startup.

Is there a way to configure Elmah emails declaratively in code rather than using the <errorMail> tag?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by overriding the `SendMail` method of Elmah's `ErrorMailModule`, as suggested by Atif Aziz in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elmah/nghfnwTjA_0) on Google Groups.

I've given more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39512434/13153).

Answer (score 0):

You could trap the Elmah Mailing event and substitute your email addresses.

http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/01/06/customizing-elmah-s-error-emails.aspx